# Does each upvote (by a user with more than 125 reputation) really raise the score of an answer or question by one?

Tags: support

Does each upvote (by a user with more than 125 reputation) really raise the score of an answer or question by one?  Or does one "unit" of displayed score really represent a much larger number of upvotes?  (I don't understand why the vote score of some questions is so low.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Voting up requires 15 rep](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up), not 125.

If a post has say 6 next to it, it means it has a net votes of 6, that can be +6, or +7/-1, for example.

>999 rep users can actually [view this breakdown](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user).

A single up/down vote from any user that can cast a vote is just +/- 1 on the post, and +10/-2 rep points to the author of the post. And users can't vote more than once on a post either.